# One Spring application forwarding requests to another Spring application

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

**Background:** We have a architecture with two applications: one handles the layout with headers and footers (Common); the other is the application itself (App).

Common has a set of filters that process the request and a servlet that forwards (dispatcher.forward) the request to App. Common was before a pure Java application and App usually Spring MVC based. Common is now being rewritten with Spring.

**Problem:** After the request has been processed in App, Common need to handle possible errors and then lookup translations from the application context message source. But instead the following exception occur:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    at org.apache.jsp.html._404_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(_404_jsp.java:162)
```

It seems that Spring looses track of the original ApplicationContext and the exception is thrown. Is there a work around for this issue? Can we separate the contexts some how. What I've seen is that Common becomes the root context and App a child to that.